# AngularJS - 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On my angular app I display a list of items that I load directly from my database. I am trying to get at least 20 items displayed at all time. Users can filter them so when too many filters are applied I'd like to load more.

The way I did it so far is the following:
HTML:

```
<section id="list" class="ease">
          <article class='myItems' ng-repeat="job in filteredList = (items | filter: country | filter: category | filter: position)">
                   Items
          </article>
</section>
```

JS (in my controller):

```
$scope.$watch('filteredList', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal !== oldVal){
        $log.info($scope.filteredList.length);
        // code to load more data
    }
});
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting
```

I am guessing it is because the filteredList change too many times so angular blocks it. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose the problem here will be somewhere in the code which is loading more data... can you share that part?

Comment: Could you provide your `// code to load more data`? This must be the issue actually ;)

Comment: actually I have the problem even when I comment the code loading the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.$watchCollection` instead of `$scope.$watch` since your `filteredList` is a collection.

Using `$scope.$watch` actually fails since you rebuild the reference on each digestion loop, so the watcher loops and loops again and reach the digest limit.

[Interesting article about the watching methods](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-Scope-watch-vs-watchCollection-In-AngularJS.htm)

Comment: one more question: how can i wait for the page to be fully loaded to have the $scope.$watchCollection working? Thanks a lot

Comment: It depends on how `items` is published on the scope. Either it's published at controller instantiation time and you can add a condition on `$scope.items` in your `filteredList` collection watcher. Or use the `resolve` attribute of your application routing.